# Indeed API: failed to open stream: Connection refused

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, curl

I m using the Indeed Job Search API to retrieve job ads on my Laravel Website.
I created a command to populate my database, and everything works fine in my local environment but not in production. These errors appear:

**- When I m testing Curl access:**

> Failed to connect to api.indeed.com port 80

**- When I m using file_get_contents:**

> ```
> file_get_contents(http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=API_KEY&q=fruit+picking&co=au&v=2&latlong=1&fromage=5&limit=10&start=0&format=json&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&userip=185.145.156.52):
> ```
>
> failed to open stream: Connection refused

I checked in the API panel on the Indeed website but I can't provide my website domain and I don't know where the problem comes from.

Here is my code :

```
public function handle() {
    $json_string_o = 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=PUBLISHER_API_KEY&q='.$request.'&co=au&v=2&latlong=1&fromage=5&limit=10&start=0&format=json&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&userip=185.145.156.52';
    $response = $this->curl_json ($json_string_o);
    $json_data_o = json_decode($response, true);
}

 public function curl_json ($url){

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $content = curl_exec ($ch);

    if(curl_error($ch))
    {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        echo $content;
    }

    curl_close ($ch);

    return $content;
}
```

Is there anyone who ever had this issue with Indeed API ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does your API works correctly in postman or browser??

Comment: Yes it works perfectly with the both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution about my problem with my hosting provider. This answer is for people who host their website in OVH.

If you try to call an API from Laravel command it will work in localhost but not in production. Actually OVH use a whitelist for external connection to use SSH command. So, two solutions are available:

1. **Curl in a controller**

You can use Curl in a controller to call your API and do whatever you want with the result. You also need to define a route to access your controller with your browser. If you open your browser at the address defined it will work.

2. **Curl in a command**

   - Create a new command and insert your code with a curl function to retrieve data from external source (indeed in my case)
   - Defined the command in Console/Kernel.php

   protected $commands = ['App\Console\Commands\YOURCOMMAND'];
   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
       {
         $schedule->command('type:command_name')->everyMinute();
       }

   - Create a new php file named schedule-run.php at the root of your server

   $_SERVER['argv'] = [
       'artisan',
       'schedule:run',
   ];

   require **DIR**.'/artisan';

   - Define a new Cron task in your OVH admin panel that redirect to the schedule-run.php file

You can run the cron task maximum once per hour in OVH this is why you need to define the frequency to 'everyMinute' in the schedule function.

Hope it will help people who are hosting their websites in OVH

Answer (score 4):

try adding adding a useragent, this helped fix the problem for me back when I was curling some stuff.

e.G:

```
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    curl_setopt($openCurl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just saw in the API documentation that I need to provide 'userip' and 'useragent' parameters to url. I did it but it doesn't work. I tried in including the user agent in the Curl function but it doesn't work neither.